# ASP.NET MVC 3: Does [RequireHttps] work with Web Farm Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, web-farm-framework

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7656463/84424) but I need it solved in a different way because you are not supposed to load SSL certs on every server (which is what we did in that question.)

If you have this in MVC3 and WWF resolves the SSL prior to delivering the request, how do you force certain Actions to be SSL?

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

This will switch from http to https, which results in a "The page isn't redirecting properly."  Any suggestions?